# Can I use the figaro gem to set env variables in my local environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, figaro-ruby

I use the Figaro gem to set env variables for my apps hosted on Heroku.

To set the required env variables on production I use this:

`$ figaro heroku:set -e production`

Can I do something similar for my *local* environment? Right now I'm manually calling `export foo=bar` for each variable.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Make sure you have it installed in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'figaro'
bundle install
```

Then run:

```
figaro:install
```

And it will generate an application.yml file.

Make sure you use add your environment variables under the respective environments:

```
development:
  my_env_var: "stuff"
test:
  my_env_var: "stuff"
```

Comment: And the variables will automatically get set when my app runs?

Comment: Yes. Just use ENV['my_env_var'] to access it. You may need to restart your server. A side note also, that it gets added to your `.gitignore` file, so it won't get pushed up with heroku or git when you make commits.